# Maven - profile activation with variables

Tags: maven, maven-3

I've got problem with auto-activation of my maven profile.
When I use variables (e.g. **${project.basedir}**) it doesn't work.

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prof1</id>

        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>${project.basedir}\mark.txt</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>...
```

When I write path without variables, it works perfect:

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prof1</id>

        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>C:\projects\trainings\own\MavenPrj\mark.txt</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>...
```

The file C:\projects\trainings\own\MavenPrj\mark.txt of course exists.

My Maven Version is 3.0.4.

Regards
Piotrek

Comment: Use `${basedir}` instead, it should work.

Comment: Side note: best practice: use slashes `/` instead of backslashes `\ `, even if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Maven's [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) :

> As of Maven 2.0.9, the tags <exists> and <missing> could be interpolated. Supported variables are system properties like ${user.home} and environment variables like ${env.HOME}. **Please note that properties and values defined in the POM itself are not available for interpolation here**, e.g. the above example activator cannot use ${project.build.directory} but needs to hard-code the path target.